# Run multiple version of NodeJs

Tags: nodejs

I am in a situation where I am managing a server with 2 different projects that run different version of NodeJs and possibly React. The projects are developed by 2 different programmers, so I just wanted to know if there is a way to avoid using containers, and allow each project to run a different version of NodeJs and ReactJs.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, is a very common situation. What you need is NVM (Node Version Manager): https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

About React, I am not sure, but as the dependencies' versions are on package.json, you can have a different version for every project, except for packages installed globally (with the -g flag).

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I did find an article that talked briefly about nvm alias. I will check this out.